# SQLite execution order, brackets not working

Tags: database, sqlite

Im trying to select rows from a table, union the result with another select statement and then order that by timestamp. 
Unfortunately it only orders the second select statement with this command:

```
SELECT message, transmitter_ename , Timestamp, didread
FROM messages
WHERE transmitter_ename= ? AND receiver_ename= ?
    UNION ALL
SELECT message,transmitter_ename , Timestamp,  didread
FROM messages
WHERE transmitter_ename= ? AND receiver_ename=?
ORDER BY Timestamp ASC
```

I tried to use brackets but SQLite doesn't accept those(Error undefined).

I couldn't find anything related to that on the web.

Comment: I've answered the question, but your query doesn't make much sense. You're `UNION ALL`ing with the same query, effectively duplicating each row.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that i turn the variables around in the second statement. So that it works both ways in the chat database. Either one can be named as either sender or receiver

Comment: The ORDER BY *does* apply to both SELECTs. Show some example data.